# Edge motion not working on Acer Aspire R15 laptop with Elan trackpad, no edge motion settings in synclient

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, elantech

In Windows 10, my trackpad has a feature where, if I double-tap and drag to the edge of the pad, the cursor will keep moving in that direction. I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 as dual boot, and that feature does not work in Ubuntu. According to my research, synclient should have settings for edge motion, but they aren't there. xinput lists my touchpad as "ELAN0501:00 04F3:3019 Touchpad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `synaptics` man page, edge motion is no longer part of the driver.  In other words, it appears this capability is no longer available.

Comment: Ah, so it is. I wonder why it was removed? Thanks.

Comment: Apparently it was "A funny feature, but unreliable and mostly untested.": https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-synaptics/commit/?h=synaptics-1.7-branch&id=54f65f3ca1f7a7118bea96915d79acee28721581